# Is a python venv wrapper enough to isolate the effects of exec in python?

Tags: python, python-venv

I'm writing a genetic algorithm for writing code, and was wondering whether a simple venv wrapper would prevent nonsense that could step from use of `exec "import os; ..."`.

I tried `exec "..." in {}`, which I had tried hoping to only make the things inside of `{}` available to exec.

Basically, I'm looking for a safe way to execute randomly generated code. Would a venv wrapper do the trick? I [read](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html) that venv could separate the virtual directory from my system's files, but I'm not sure I read that correctly.

Comment: No, not at all. Search for chroot (Linux) or sandbox in general.

Comment: Virtual environments are for dependency management, not for isolation process isolation.